# lying Leg raises, hand under head

Tags: abdominals

While doing lying leg raises, I keep my hands under my head instead of keep them straight on the floor. I feel it puts more pressure on abdominal mussels. Will it have any side effect as I have not seen any one doing lying leg raises like this.
This posture is like this assume a person doing lying leg raises on floor, and he doesn't puts his hand near or under its hips but puts them under their head,

Comment: Possible to upload any pictures of yourself exercising? Or can you further elaborate the posture?

Comment: I think I get the exercise the OP is trying to depict - Lying leg raise, with hand behind the ears, head and shoulder off the ground like in crunches (although OP hasn't mentioned this part).

I came across this exercise in Jillian Micheals' Yoga Meltdown dvd. This version of lying leg raise makes me feel more on my lower back and abs than one with hands lying on floor near hips.

Comment: yes, I am talking about that

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, daily I do leg raises but on a bench with hands holding head end of the bench (almost same as lying on floor).

I never felt it uncomfortable and there are no side effects AFAIK (I am doing it from quite a long time).

In fact, I felt it more comfortable than lying on floor version.

Comment: This is the same approach I use.  Legs are hanging off the bench so that I have to keep the abs engaged when the legs are at the bottom position.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch - Exactly. Legs hanging off completely engage lower abs and keep constant tension.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your hands by your side during leg raises *(while lying on your back)* or reverse crunches allows your hands to support your abs and that reduces the efficacy of the exercise. 
 
Putting your hands behind your head allows only your abs muscles *(along with your thigh muscles)* to perform the exercises. This is much more effective; however, it's harder to perform. 
 
As far as I know, there isn't any side effect to doing it that way and *(assuming you use proper forms)* you should feel the effect much better than supporting the abs muscles with your hands.